# How to migrate data to Alfresco from Ftp servers as data sources?

Tags: alfresco

The Situation: I'm going to implement a digital repository using alfresco community version 5.1 to manage our university digital content which is stored at a moment in differents ftp servers (software installers, books, thesis). I intent to use alfresco as a backend and Orchard CMS as our intranet frontend which is a non functional requierement and communicate both with CMIS. The general idea is that we use a social networking approch in which every user can modify metadata, add tags in order to improve the search, which by the way is the general objective of my work (allows searches and download to the digital content of our intranet , because right know it takes a lot of time to find anything because it is storage in a ftp server without a good cataloging).
I already successfully created a custom data model but when a decided to migrate the content from these ftps, i didn't find any documentation about it. I read about bulk import tool but it happent that i need the data locally in the same computer that runs alfresco, and as i said, the data source are different ftp server. 
So How can i migrate data from differents ftps servers as datasource to Alfresco?. Is it necessary to physically import files to Alfresco or can i work with index pointing to the ftp files (keep the files in the ftps and have in Alfresco a reference of that object (I only have search and download functional requierements))?.
Please I need your help as a guidence because here in cuba we dont have experience working with Alfresco and it is very difficult to have access to internet. So if you can point out the way of fixing this, or any recommendation i will be forever greatfull. Thank You and Again so sorry to disturb You

Comment: Files on those various FTP servers, do they have any metadata? Would this be a one time migration or an ongoing synchronization? Also, where in Alfresco would they end up (folder structure, different sites)?

Comment: Thanks 4 ur reply, Yes i would like to recover as many metadata as i can and i would like to do an ongoing synchronization and they would end up in a folder structure. But i am open minded about it. You are more experienced  than I am, so if you have any recomendation or suggestion that involve makinh some change  please let me know

Answer (score 1):

If this were a one-time thing, you could use an FTP client of some sort to simply drag and drop the files from your FTP server into Alfresco's FTP server. This would copy the files only and would not set any custom metadata.

Alternatively, you could write some Java to do this. Java can read from FTP servers and can write to Alfresco via CMIS. This would give you the opportunity to set some properties on the objects written into Alfresco beyond just the file name, creation date, and modification date.

However, if you are going to do this regularly, you might want to look at an integration tool. For example, you could use [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/ftp.html) to watch the FTP servers, and when there is a change, it could fetch the file and write it to Alfresco via CMIS.

This will likely take some coding to make it work exactly right, but hopefully this gives you some options to consider.